# Kubernetes: communicate internal services using HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes, https, kubernetes-ingress

I have 2 services deployed in Kubernetes

1. Application A (asp.net core 5 gRPC service)
2. Application B (asp.net core 5 api)

Application B is accessible via ingress-nginx-controller over https from out side of my cluster.

Application A is expose via Service and only accessible inside my cluster.

My question is how can I connect from Application B to Application A over SSL/TLS?

[image]

Comment: The sole aim of SSL is to keep traffic encrypted, why do you need this if the services are inside your same cluster only

Comment: I need this because gRPC In Asp.net Core 5 is not working without SSL/TLS.

Comment: there are mechanisms in gRPC even to disable the SSL, the HTTP/2 paradigm intrinsically provides SSL, you can choose to disable it as well, inside the cluster, you won't need that

Comment: I tried that but somehow that`s not worked for asp.net core 5 but worked for asp.net core 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

For HTTPS communication, you can setup certificate with "dotnet dev-certs https". Each pod will need setup self-signed certificate on port 443, for development purpose, but not recommended.

However, GRPC actually can be use with HTTP based, with service mesh support for http2/grpc for service-to-service communication. These steps can be

1. Call GRPC use HTTP

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-3.0#call-insecure-grpc-services-with-net-core-client-2
2. Setup Linkerd

   https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/meshing-with-linkerd2-using-grpc-enabled-net-core-services/ba-p/1377867

Hope this helps